# I need help in managing this file

Tags: javascript, flutter, visual-studio-code

How do I change the order of files from alphabetical order to last added?[image]

I don't know where the settings are , I have a lot of trouble managing those files

Comment: please post the code not an image

Answer (score 3):

The setting you are looking for is

```json
    "explorer.sortOrder": "modified"
```

which will sort them by the date they were last modified. To add this to your settings, you can either create `.vscode/settings.json` and add this field there, or use Ctrl + Shift + P to open the command palette, then selecting "Open Settings (JSON)", and then adding the field in there.

Creating `.vscode/settings.json` is a workspace specific setting - meaning that it will only affect your editor when this specific workspace is open.

However, I don't think you can sort by last *added* or *created* - plus, that doesn't really make sense. Why would you want to sort by *creation date*? I doubt you'll remember when you created each file and it'll be difficult to navigate your file structure.

Answer (score 1):

In your Settings **(File → Preferences → Settings)** search for: `explorer.sortOrder` and then change to `modified`
[image]